# polyfit() not following the data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Here is my code:

```
clear all
close all
clc


%% abdomen

apAbdWat = [5.7 7.4 11.2 14.9 18.6 22.4 26.1 29.8 33.6];
latAbdWat = [7.7 10 15    20   25    30   35 40    45];

apTisAbd = [8.9 11.4 13.9 15.9 18.4 22 24.9 30.7];
latTisAbd = [10.6 14 18 20.6 24 30 32.4 38.9];

apAnthAbd = [20.8];
latAnthAbd = [28.3];

figure
plot(apAbdWat, latAbdWat, '-+'); hold on;
plot(apTisAbd, latTisAbd, 'r-o'); hold on;
plot(apAnthAbd, latAnthAbd, '-k*')

xlabel('AP diameter (cm)')
ylabel('LAT diameter (cm)')
title('AP diameter vs. LAT diameter (abdomen phantom) ')
legend('water abdomen', 'tissue abdomen', 'anthrop abdomen');

x = [apAbdWat apTisAbd apAnthAbd];
y = [latAbdWat latTisAbd latAnthAbd];

[p,S,mu] = polyfit(y,x,1);
hold on; t = 1:40;
plot(t,p(1)*t+p(2), 'g-')
```

Here is what I have got:
[image]

Shouldn't the green line follow the rest of all the points pretty well? I cannot figure out where I did wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- `x` and `y` are interchanged in your line containing [`polyfit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).
- The three-output version of [`polyfit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) doesn't give a polynomial in `x`. To obtain a polynomial in `x` you use the two-output version.

From the documentation (format added to highlight the two above issues):

> POLYFIT Fit polynomial to data.
>
> P = POLYFIT(**X,Y**,N) finds the coefficients of a polynomial P(X) [...]
>
> [P,S] = POLYFIT(X,Y,N) returns the polynomial coefficients P and a
>       structure S [...]
>
> [P,S,MU] = POLYFIT(X,Y,N) finds the coefficients of a polynomial **in
>       XHAT = (X-MU(1))/MU(2)** where MU(1) = MEAN(X) and MU(2) = STD(X) [...]

So, change your line

```
[p,S,mu] = polyfit(y,x,1);
```

to

```
[p,S] = polyfit(x,y,1);
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your getting the wrong variable, you may edit your code as follows:

```
p= polyfit(y,x,1);
t=1:1:40;
hold on;plot(x,polyval(p,x),'r');
```

[image]